# Extending sphinx.ext.graphviz with additional extension

Tags: python-sphinx, graphviz

I would like to extend the built-in sphinx-doc extension sphinx.ext.graphviz with a few featues. As the features are very special for my use case i do not want to extend sphinx.ext.graphviz itself.

Essentially i just want to ([graphviz sources for reference](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/ext/graphviz.py))

- parse with graphviz to get the graphviz nodes (~ Graphviz.run()),
- modify the graphviz dotcode of the nodes (~ node['code'] = dotcode),
- output/render (html/pdf) with graphviz without modification (~ e.g. for
  html: html_visit_graphviz() -> render_dot_html()).

I have read the [sphinx-doc extension developer guide](http://sphinx-doc.org/extdev/index.html#dev-extensions) but do not fully
understand the build phases/procedure and how to "combine" extensions like described above.

Is it possible to modifiy the inlined graphviz code between "Build Phase
1: Reading" and "Build Phase 3: Resolving" somehow using an additional
sphinx extension which "invokes" sphinx.ext.graphviz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided by a sphinx-doc contributor [https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2246]:

Maybe you can do it with following code:

```
def on_doctree_read(app, doctree):
    for node in doctree.traverse(graphviz):
        code = re.sub('\];', ', color = red];', node['code'])  # change color of nodes and edges
        node['code'] = code


def setup(app):
    app.connect('doctree-read', on_doctree_read)
```

In this example, I used the doctree-read event. It is raised at Reading phase. In more detail, you can see what is "Sphinx core events" at http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/extdev/appapi.html#sphinx-core-events